# ThreeJS - Manually set Pivot point for loaded GLTF model

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

Hi I have GLTF model and I loaded it into my ThreeJS scene using the following code:

```
gltfLoader.load('assets/models/coin/scene.gltf', (gltf) => {
        const root = gltf.scene;

        gltf.scene.traverse(function(node){
          if ( node.isMesh ) { 
            node.castShadow = true;
            node.receiveShadow = true;
            if(node.material.map) {
              node.material.map.anisotropy = 16;
            }
          }
        })

        // root.position.set(25, 120, -500);
        root.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        root.scale.set(20, 20, 20);

        coinBox = new THREE.BoxHelper( root, 0xffff00 );
        scene.add(coinBox);

        coin = root;
        scene.add(root);

        //Adding a circle to visualize the pivot point
        const circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(3, 64);
        const circleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
        const circleMesh = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry, circleMaterial);
        circleMesh.position.copy(root.position);
        circleMesh.position.y += 1;
        scene.add(circleMesh);
      });
```

I added a `CircleGeometry` to visualize where the Pivot point of this object is.
It turns out, the pivot point is not in the center of the model.

So when I perform the following code:

`coin.rotation.z += 0.01;`, it rotates around the wrong pivot point (The red dot in the GIF)

[image]

Is there a way for me to manually change the pivot point or center position of this model based on the meshes that are loaded in?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without knowing what's inside `scene.gltf`.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot explicitly change the pivot point, but you can do this:
first, in order to proceed with this method you need to manage the 3D object hierarchy in the scene, then:

- define the bounding box for the object in question:

  const pivot_box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( circleMesh );
- calculate the center of the mesh:

  const piv_center = new THREE.Vector3();

  pivot_box.getCenter(piv_center)
- move the mesh to the origin of the axes:

  circleMesh.position.sub(piv_center)
- create a THREE.Group object that will be the parent of the circleMesh (named eg: newPivotBox)
- attach the circleMesh to the object just defined
- attach newPivotBox to the scene
- interact with the newPivotBox object for rotation, translation and scaling

this is how i managed the same problem, i hope it can help you.